# React, Why does the state received by useLocation always indicate Null?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with `useLocation`, whatever happens it returns `null`. So, I can't get the data from one page to another.

I am using `react-router-dom` and the `Links` to pass the data through `state`. In the course that I am taking, it works, but this part may not be up to date.

The state of console.log in Contact returns :

```
{pathname: '/Contact', search: '', hash: '', state: null, key: 'za46e86p'}
```

Instead of returning :

```
{pathname: '/Contact', search: '', hash: '', state: {txt: "je mange des poissons"}, key: 'za46e86p'}
```

FILE App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Accueil from './Components/Accueil'
import Projets from './Components/Projets'
import Contact from './Components/Contact'
import Erreur404 from './Components/Erreur'
import Nav from './Components/Nav/Nav'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
 
 
function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <BrowserRouter>
 
          <Nav />
 
          <Routes> 
            <Route path="/"  element={<Accueil />} />
            <Route path="/Projets"  element={<Projets />} />
            <Route path="/Projets/:slug"  element={<Projets />} />
            <Route path="/Contact"  element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path="*"  element={<Erreur404 />} />
          </Routes>
 
        </BrowserRouter>
 
    </>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

FILE Nav.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Nav.css'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Nav() {
    return (
        <ul className="nav-list">
            <NavLink  to="/">
                <li>Accueil</li>
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink  to="/Projets">
                <li>Projets</li>
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink  to="/Contact">
                <li>Contact</li>
            </NavLink>
        </ul>
    )
}
```

FILE Accueil.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
 
export default function Accueil() {
    return (
        <>
          <h1>Bienvenue ACCUEIL</h1>  
          <Link
          to={{
            pathname: "/Contact",
            state: {
              txt: "je mange des poissons"
            }
          }}> Aller à la section Contact </Link>
        </>
    )
}
```

File Contact.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
 
export default function Contact() {
 
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location);
 
    return (
        <>
          <h1>Section CONTACT</h1>  
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Just making sure, you are testing it with the link in `Accueil.js` and not the one in `Nav.js`, right?
Since in the latter, you do not pass a state value.

Comment: thank you for watching ! indeed yes, i click on the link in Accueil.js, unfortunately that doesn't change anything

Comment: Yeah, I do the same even I wrapped the whole thing and didn't work. Still null!